# Where does Qt Designer store the signal to slot connections?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

In Qt Designer, I have connected a pushButton to a slot. **But where is this information stored?** I cannot find it in the (xml) ui-file.

(In addition, I would like to remove the connection. How can I do that?)

Comment: Aren't there a `<connection>` elements, in ui file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All slots that are named:

```
void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);
```

are [automatically connected](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#automatic-connections) to specified widget and signal, after the `ui->setupUi` method are called.